# install subprocess on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute this script and it won't run.  I believe that subprocess is not installed based on the error message.  I am using python 3.9 on a Mac.  I thought that python 3 already had subprocess in it's default library, but I could be wrong.  When I try to do a pip or pip3 install subprocess, it doesn't work either.  Not sure how to make this work.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import subprocess

network = '10.21.30.'

def hostList(number):
    hosts = []
    count = 1
    while (count <= number):
        hosts.append((network + str(count)))
        count += 1
    return hosts

def ping_test (host):

    reached = []                           #Empty list to collect reachable hosts
    not_reached = []                          #Empty list to collect unreachable hosts

    for ip in host:
        ping_test = subprocess.call('ping %s -n 2' % ip)        #Ping host n times
        if ping_test == 0:                    #If ping test is 0, it' reachable
            reached.append(ip)

        else:
            not_reached.append(ip)                              #Else, it's not reachable

    print("{} is reachable".format(reached))
 

#hosts = ["192.168.1.1","123.214.2.2","www.google.com",]
ping_test(hostList(254))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/ex5.py", line 32, in <module>
    ping_test(hosts)
  File "/Users/user/Documents//ex5.py", line 21, in ping_test
    ping_test = subprocess.call('ping %s -n 2' % ip)        #Ping host n times
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 349, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1823, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ping 192.168.1.1 -n 2'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is a bit cryptic but you want to either

- Split your arguments to `subprocess.call` (or better [`subprocesses.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)) into a list e.g.

```py
subprocess.run(["ping", "stackoverflow.com"])
```

or

- Add the `shell=True` option

```py
subprocess.run("ping stackoverflow.com", shell=True)
```

for the second option be sure to read the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).